# refresh to much data after executeUpdate

Tags: grails, load

I use grails 2.2.3 and have a problem with my grails apps.

I have few classes :

```
class Block {
[...]
    String myPropName 
    Rule rule
[...]
    static mapping = {
[...]
    rulecolumn: 'RULEID'
[...]
}
class Rule {
[...]
    static hasMany = [lkrRuleCrit: LkrRuleCrit]
[...]
    static mapping = {
[...]
        lkrRuleCrit joinTable: [name: 'LK_RULE_CRIT', key: 'RULEID' ]
[...]
}
class LkrRuleCrit implements Serializable{
    Rule rule   
    String  CriteriaValue   
    static mapping = {          
        id composite: ['RuleID', 'CriteriaType']        
        table 'LkrRuleCrit_T'       
        Rule column: 'RULEID' ,lazy: true
        CriteriaType column: 'CRITERIA_TYPE_ID'  ,lazy: true
    }
}
```

- Block => N lines
- Rule  => 100 000 000 lines
- LkrRuleCrit => Rule x 100 lines

A simple update of Block.myPropName is really slow in production because of the amount of data.

In debug I see that after my block.executeUpdate("update of myPropName ") the framework do :

a select of all the Block updated 
and a select of LkrRuleCrit where RULEID is the on of the Block which is not required and possible in this case (I have a link in this for specific use)

How could I disable the refresh of all linked object please ?

I have played which :

`mapping {
    cache true 
}`

And with lazy without any effect...

Thanks !

JF

Answer (score 0):

I answer to myself.

Never ever use the org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder to produce toString method of Domain class like :

```
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this)
}
```

It was the cause of all my trouble.